# Building a priority_queue of pairs

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, priority-queue

I frequently come across the problem of needing a priority queue that stores `std::pair<int, T>`, `std::tuple<int, T>`, or `std::array<int, 2>` where elements are ordered by the first entry of the pair.

For example, the entries `[4, 2]`, `[2, 4]`, `[1, 1]`, and `[3, 3]` would be ordered as:

`[1, 1]` < `[2, 4]` < `[3, 3]` < `[4, 2]`.

I eventually figure out how to get what I want, but it is always messy. I will provide some examples below.

I might try something like:

```
#include <queue>

struct SomeKindOfPair {
    int ordered_element;
    int unordered_element;
};

int main() {
    
    std::priority_queue<SomeKindOfPair> my_queue([](SomeKindOfPair a, SomeKindOfPair b) {return a.ordered_element > b.ordered_element; });

    return 0;
}
```

My intent here was to use constructor (2) from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) and allow the Comparer type to be deduced by the compiler. This will cause the compiler to throw an error and I'm not sure why. For completeness, the error is

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'main::<lambda_1>' to 'const _Pr &'
with _Pr=std::less<SomeKindOfPair>
```

This is what I have gotten to work. As you can see, it is messy:

```
#include <queue>

struct SomeKindOfPair {
    int ordered_element;
    int unordered_element;
};

class MyComparer {
public:
    bool operator()(SomeKindOfPair a, SomeKindOfPair b) {
        return a.ordered_element > b.ordered_element;
    }

};

int main() {

    MyComparer comparer{};

    std::priority_queue<SomeKindOfPair, std::vector<SomeKindOfPair>, MyComparer> my_queue{ comparer };

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Specifically:

1. Can I do this without defining a `MyComparer` class?
2. Can I do this without having to write out the full template specialization of `priority_queue`, `std::priority_queue<SomeKindOfPair, std::vector<SomeKindOfPair>, MyComparer>`?
3. Can I do this without having to name the comparison operator anywhere (define it as a lambda where I construct the `priority_queue`)?

and, less importantly

4. Because most online judges still use old versions of the C++ standard, can I do this in a way that is compatible with older C++ standards (in particular C++14)?
5. Can I do this without using `decltype`, if doing so will disable the use of Concepts where applicable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [first form of the deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/deduction_guides) for `std::priority_queue`:

```
template <class Comp, class Container>
priority_queue(Comp, Container)
 -> priority_queue<typename Container::value_type, Container, Comp>;
```

Then

```
std::vector<SomeKindOfPair> v;
std::priority_queue my_queue(
  [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {return a.ordered_element > b.ordered_element; }, v);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vz36o8f4n)

Comment: This is better, but I am sure you agree that passing the ```priority_queue``` an empty ```vector``` just to pattern match is messy. As demonstrated in my second example, there are constructors that do not require a container, and these are preferable.

Comment: Before knowing what the type of `Compare` is, we must first know what the type of `Container` is.

Comment: We can specify the type of ```Container``` to be ```std::vector<SomeKindOfPair>``` without ever constructing that vector ourselves. It appears to me that the deduction guide deals with situations where the user wants to provide both a ```Container``` and a ```Compare````. Ideally, I would not need to use these constructors.